# using celery flower in docker-compose with auth

Tags: docker, docker-compose, flower

I'm executing celery flower image mher/flower with docker-compose
I want to setup auth for same, I tried adding environment variable basic_auth,
however that's not working.

Is there any way to setup creds for flower

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the flower service in your docker compose file to use basic auth:

```
environment:
  - FLOWER_BASIC_AUTH=username:password
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I found was to use command like

```
command: "--basic_auth=admin:admin"
```